# Creating a file for each response from an API call with a FOR loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to create a file for each response from an API call with a for loop, but when i try to use interop it give the error:

> i is not defined even though it is define when the loop uses it to make API calls

```
function sysWrite(data){
  fs.appendFile(`${testArray[i}[1]}.json`, data, function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
  })
}

forLoop().then(function (resSet){
  for(i = 0; i < resSet.length; i++){
    (function(i){
      setTimeout(function(){
        axios.get(`https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs5?get=NAME,${resSet[i]}&for=state:*&key=${censusAPI}`)
        .then(function (response) {
          //problem place
          let replacedKey = Object.assign({}, response.data);
          let jsonData =  JSON.stringify(replacedKey).replace(testArray[i][0], testArray[i][1]);
          sysWrite(jsonData)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }, 100*i)
    })(i);
  }
})
```

Comment: `i` is not defined in `sysWrite`. How would that function know what `i` is? You also have a seeming bug in that string template (two end curly brackets).

Comment: I don't know how the function would know what `i` is that is my problem and everything i j have tried hasn't worked. Do you have any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem:

In the 'sysWrite' function, the function references 'testArray[i][1]' which is undefined in the current context.

In addition, the 'sysWrite' function has a typo, where it says '`${testArray[i}[1]}.json`', there should be `${testArray[i][1]}.json` (You closed the array index with a curley bracket instead of a square one).

> Simple explanation:

When you call 'sysWrite', all your local variables are non-existent in that context.

Heres a good reference to learn about variables:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

> Simple solution:

```
function sysWrite(name, data){
      fs.appendFile(`${name}.json`, data, function(err){
        if(err) throw err;
      })
    }

forLoop().then(function (resSet){
  for(i = 0; i < resSet.length; i++){
    (function(i){
      setTimeout(function(){
        axios.get(`https://api.census.gov/data/2016/acs/acs5?get=NAME,${resSet[i]}&for=state:*&key=${censusAPI}`)
        .then(function (response) {
          //problem place
          let replacedKey = Object.assign({}, response.data);
          let jsonData =  JSON.stringify(replacedKey).replace(testArray[i][0], testArray[i][1]);
          sysWrite(testArray[i][1], jsonData);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
      }, 100*i)
    })(i);
  }
})
```